# Is there any way to lock the screen without turning off the display?

Tags: lock-screens

I just purchase a Nexus S.

Currently, to lock the screen, I need to

1. Press the power button.
2. Screen locked.
3. Display turned off.

To unlock screen, I need to

1. Press the power button to make screen visible.
2. Slide the touch screen to unlock.

Is there any way I can?

---

1. Press a button to lock the screen.
2. The screen remains visible, but get much less bright to preserve power.

---

1. Slide the touch screen to unlock.
2. Brightness of the screen back to normal.

Comment: I am guessing some themes do this job. Not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of such an app/feature right now, but you could use the collective effect of a couple of apps to get almost the desired thing.

1. [Lightning Bug](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.media1908.lightningbug): This is a cool free app that has
   always-on display feature and shows the clock, (and weather, etc.) and
   more.
2. [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor): This app will allow you to reduce the
   brightness even lower than what the Android system would allow you
   to.

However, when you want to put your device into standby, you will need to open these apps to get the effect. Also, running these apps does not mean it's in "lock" mode.

I see a great potential for an app that does both of these together and also put the device into lock mode at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.iml.widget.devicelock&feature=search_result) for locking your screen with just one click.

What exactly do you mean by your second question?

Comment: I think you misunderstood -- he's not looking for a one-click lock, he already has that. He's just looking for a way to lock the screen without the screen turning off.

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue with my s5, the screen flickers and once it dims it's hard to turn back on. So i downloaded keep screen on app so it doesn't turn off, then i downloaded touch lock app to prevent apps from being pressed when it's in my pocket.

Comment: Which apps did you use?

Answer (score -2):

The app is called [Advanced Screen Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=advanced.screen.control), the feature is called Proximity Wakelock and its based on the proximity sensor.

Its my app.  :-)

Comment: Are you sure the app does what the question asks? As far as I understood from the app description, it just locks the screen, but doesn't dim the screen or leave the screen visible.